# Help troubleshooting: wavy/lifting lines

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting

Can someone help me troubleshoot? Seems like it's sticking to the bed, but not well, as lines are somewhat wavy or lifting. Is it related to adhesion? Or maybe I need to clean my extruder?

I think I'm levelling the bed too close to the extruder.  Maybe it's rubbing or the heat from the extruding is warping it.

[image]

Comment: Your nozzle is probably too close to the bed, use a thicker piece of paper. Please look at [this answer](/a/7232/), it describes what to do against the waves in the first layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[What causes ripples on part of first layer?](/q/7229)".